# How to send JSON parameters in pure Javascript XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

how do I write below code in pure javascript?

```
jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', 
  { quantity: 1,  id: 26449060865  },
  { quantity: 2,  id: 26449101569 },
  { quantity: 3, id: 26449251265  },
   null,
   "json"
 );
```

Comment: That will send application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoded data, not JSON data.

Comment: That's not a valid jQuery call. Did you mean to put all the objects in an array?

Comment: What is the `null` argument for?

Comment: If you don't need a callback, just omit that argument. jQuery figures out which arguments you've specified by checking the data type.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch might be useful reading. P.S. the other comments are correct, your code above is not valid, and even if it was, it still wouldn't send the data in JSON format.

Comment: @ADyson I'm pretty sure he's making the common mistake of referring to JavaScript objects as JSON, he's not talking about the serialized format.

Comment: @Barmar true, that's very possible. OTOH I've also seen people assume that providing an object (instead of, say, a string in querystring format) to the "data" argument means it will be serialised to JSON automatically. Hard to know. Either way he needs to make a valid jQuery request and get it working before worrying about how to convert it to fetch or XHR :-)

Comment: The post data you want to send should  be formatted like `quantity[]=1&id[]=26449060865&quantity[]=2&id[]=26449101569&...`. You can send it with `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()`.

Answer (score -1):

But I would suggest you should fetch.

If you want to use XMLHttpRequest then here is the code.

````
const theUrl = "/cart/add";
xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(
  { quantity: 1,  id: 26449060865  },
  { quantity: 2,  id: 26449101569 },
  { quantity: 3, id: 26449251265  }
)); ```
````

Comment: Did you run `JSON.stringify(
  { quantity: 1,  id: 26449060865  },
  { quantity: 2,  id: 26449101569 },
  { quantity: 3, id: 26449251265  })` to see what happens?

Comment: he said his body is like that but I think if u put those object inside the object it will work.

Comment: It's impossible for his request body to be like that. It's not valid JSON and it's not a valid single object to be strinfigied either. Like I said, did you try it yourself before answering? It would make sense to post an answer which has some chance of not producing a JavaScript error